# Django CMS CKeditor

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-cms

Can anyone tell me how I restrict the editor to only allow h1 and h2 under the Format attribute in the CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_TITLE = {
    'language': '{{ language }}',
    'toolbar_HTMLField': [
        ['Format']
    ]
}
```

Comment: Make extra toolbar with custom name in settings.py and add only needed plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `format_tags` option to select the formats available in CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_TITLE = {
    'language': '{{ language }}',
    'toolbar_HTMLField': [
        ['Format']
    ],
    'format_tags': 'h1;h2'
}
```